# Check if the ASP Button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to check if the Reset(asp button) button is clicked.

**Using HTML Button:**

I am able to check if the HTML button is clicked by using **name** property of HTML button as:

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["ResetButton"]))
    {
        ResetGame();
    }
```

The HTML button looks like:

```
<button name="ResetButton" id="btnReset" value="Hello" runat="server" onclick="btnReset_Click" text="Reset" title="Reset"/>
```

**Using ASP Button**

Not able to do it. How to check if the asp:button is clicked?

Comment: Why do you need the `name` attribute? You can access the `id` (btnReset) from code behind.

Comment: btnReset.Attributes["name"] or btnReset.Attributes.Add["name", "value"]

Comment: Id asp control's inside some GridView or Repeater or something, where its not available in codebehind, then you can use: e.Item.FindControl("<id_of_asp_control>");

Comment: Don't access server side controls using `Request.Form["Name"]`.

Comment: if you see the `rendered html` of the `asp.net` `button`, you will find `name` attribute which is also `rendered` and is ends with the `button id` concatenated with the container control hierarchy separated by a special character.

Comment: I am trying to check if the button was clicked.

Comment: I think you should reword your question to ask about what you are actually doing. Asking about a specific think that might be wrong in the first place will just be confusing. e.g. Are you trying to get a button click event on an HTML button instead of an asp button?

Comment: you can call a `JavaScript` function which will set a `HiddenField` on click of that button ;)

Comment: Exactly *where* do you need that check? Your code will call the serverside clickhandler `btnReset_Click` if and only if that button is clicked. So that's where you want to call the `ResetGame()`

Comment: @HansKesting When the button is clicked, I need to call ResetGame() and then Page_Load(). But, since the Page_Load is called automatically before "btnReset_Click", I have to call the ResetGame() in the starting in Page_Load if the button was clicked.

Comment: @Codingman - you could handle the reset-click and then **redirect** to the same page. This gives you a fresh start on the page. (see also [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get))

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know the name of your control. The name will depend on the other controls in the page (the control tree). But you know that will always end with `Button1` (the ID of the `asp:Button` control). So you can get the posted value like this:

```
var resetButton = "";
foreach (string s in req.Form.AllKeys)
{
    if (s.EndsWith("Button1"))
    {
        resetButton = req.Form[s];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you have a control like

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

then at code behind you can access as below

```
Button1.Text ="SomeText";
```

Comment: He isn't talking about the Text but the name